# exportação para pdf de uma aplicação Web, erro: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, java

Boa noite. Estou querendo fazer a exportação para PDF de uma aplicação Web com JSF e estou tendo o seguinte erro:

**Stack Trace:**

> ```
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook
>     at org.primefaces.component.export.ExporterFactory.getExporterForType(ExporterFactory.java:30)
>     at org.primefaces.component.export.DataExporter.processAction(DataExporter.java:88)
>     at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:814)
>     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
>     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook
>     at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1783)
>     at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
>     ... 40 more
> ```

**Trecho do código:**

```xml
                    <p:dataTable id="estoques" value="#{estoqueBean.estoques}" var="obj" paginator="true" rows="5">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{msgs.titulotabelacadastrodeproduto}" />
                            <h:commandLink>
                                <p:graphicImage value="imagens/excel.png" width="24"/>
                                <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="estoques" fileName="estoque" />
                            </h:commandLink>

                            <h:commandLink>
                                <p:graphicImage value="imagens/pdf.png" width="24"/>
                                <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="estoques" fileName="estoque" />
                            </h:commandLink>

                            <h:commandLink>
                                <p:graphicImage value="imagens/csv.png" width="24"/>
                                <p:dataExporter type="csv" target="estoques" fileName="estoque" />
                            </h:commandLink>
                        </f:facet>
```

**Agradeço pela atenção.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe o que temos no seu stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook
```

Ou seja, o Java não conseguiu encontrar a classe `Workbook` que é utilizada pelo seu projeto.

Esse erro normalmente indica um problema de classpath. Certifique-se que a biblioteca do POI esteja em seu classpath. Você pode encontrar a versão mais recente aqui: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/poi/3.15/poi-3.15.jar

Também vale a pena verificar se as demais bibliotecas que o POI usa estão presentes. No caso da versão 3.15 do POI, são elas o Commons-Collections 4.1 e o Commons-Codec 1.10.

Os links dessas bibliotecas seguem abaixo:

- Commons collections: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-collections4/4.1/commons-collections4-4.1.jar
- Commons codec: http://central.maven.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.jar ou https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10.0.redhat-5/commons-codec-1.10.0.redhat-5.jar - Não sei qual dessas duas é melhor (provavelmente tanto faz), mas não use as duas juntas, use apenas uma.